# How can I fix three test case errors without no input and output information?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the following Codewars challenge [Vasya - Clerk](https://www.codewars.com/kata/555615a77ebc7c2c8a0000b8/discuss):

> The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of
>   people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them
>   has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollar bill. An "Avengers" ticket costs 25
>   dollars.
>
> Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to
>   every single person in this line.
>
> Can Vasya sell a ticket to every person and give change if he
>   initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order
>   people queue?
>
> Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to every person and give change
>   with the bills he has at hand at that moment. Otherwise return NO.

My code passed the sample tests, but my submission was rejected for three test cases.

**Problem**

There is no information about the test cases for which my program fails.

How can I fix my current code to pass the tests?

```
 Passed: 17 Failed: 3 Exit Code: 1
```

[image]

**Program**

```py
def tickets(people):
    Vasya_wallet = 0
    if len(people) <0:
        return "NO"

    for i in range(len(people)):
        if people[i] != 25 and Vasya_wallet <= (people[i]-25):
            return "NO"

        elif Vasya_wallet >= (people[i] - 25):
             Vasya_wallet = Vasya_wallet + 25 - (people[i] - 25)

    return "YES"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are actually collecting the money and simply adding them up in `Vasya_wallet` which is not what the question asks you to do.
- The question is more about whether you can give change to user in terms of `$50` and `$25` notes.
- So, we have to collect them in different variables, check their availability and return a `YES` or a `NO` to satisfy all accordingly.

**Logic:**

- If the user pays `$25`, no change has to be returned as that this the ticket price. However, we increase `var_25` count by 1 as shown in the below code.
- If we receive a `$50`, we return back `$25` change only if we have one. Else, we return a `NO` if it's not possible. **Note** that in this context, user has to be paid the change immediately instead of making him to wait for some time to give him back the change. That makes this problem more simpler.
- If we receive a `$100`, we have to give him back change of `$75` in the form of either  `$50,$25` or `$25,$25,$25` depending upon the availability. However, we go for a greedy approach to return `$50,$25` if we have one. We do this because `$25` is the highest common factor of `$25,$50,$75` meaning, we can make any of them with `$25`s but it's not possible to make other changes with these.

**Snippet:**

```
def tickets(people):
    var_25 = 0
    var_50 = 0
    for i in range(len(people)):
        if people[i] == 25:
            var_25 += 1
        elif people[i] == 50:
            if var_25 == 0: # if we have no change to give back, we return NO
                return "NO"
            var_25 -= 1 #we give the user $25 change back
            var_50 += 1 # now, we have a $50 change with us
        else: # if the user gives $100 to us
            if var_25 == 0 or var_25 * 25 + var_50 * 50 < 75: # if we can't give $75 change back
                return "NO"
            if var_50 > 0:
                var_50 -= 1 # we give him one $50 and one $25 change back
                var_25 -= 1
            else:
                var_25 -= 3 # or we give 3 $25 change as we don't have $50 change

    return "YES"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a "blackboxed" testing system (the system provides some examples but specifically doesn't publish what it actually uses for validation to avoid trial-and-error or special casing of each test case) you need to write your own cases based on the specifications to try and fix boundary conditions.

Some sort of randomised generator (or a full-blown property-testing tool like *hypothesis*) can be very useful if you manage to define sensible properties.

Incidentally and aside from the code being debatable the issue is that you're miscomputing the problem *and* treating bills as fungible numbers.

First is

> ```
> Vasya_wallet + 25 - (people[i] - 25)
> ```

here if the person has $100, Vasya should end up at +25 (gets 100, gives back 75) however you're saying that Vasya *loses 50* (+25 - 100 +25), the patron gets a free ticket and 50 bucks.

Second you're misunderstanding the problem: bills are bills, once you get a 100 bill *you have an indivisible 100 bill* you can't just take 100 and create 4x25 out of thin air, so you have to account for the bills you have specifically, and draw from those to give money back to the patrons (though you can probably ignore $100 bills as they're not useful for change). That doesn't mean your till decreases, is should still increase by 25 per patron. That means your "Vasya_wallet" check is also incorrect, Vasya can have $25000 in the till and still not be able to give change on a $50 bill if they have only 50s and 100s.